# What's the standard way to install modules from the Python Standard Library into a local directory?

Tags: python, environment-variables, python-module

I've found that the admin of the server I'm using tends to leave python modules extremely outdated and I don't have time to wait for this person to update the global directories.

Is there any way I can have my local python modules take precedence over the global libraries without manually modifying the sys.path?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are various options.  If you are using Python 2.6 or later, you can install Python modules in your home directory using the [user installation scheme](http://docs.python.org/install/index.html#inst-alt-install-user) supported by Python's Distutils.  Just add `--user` to the `setup.py install` command as described in the link.  Another popular option is to use the third-party [`virtualenv`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) package to create one or more isolated local Python environments.

UPDATE:  For the `user installation scheme`, checking for the user site-packages directory is done during Python startup.  If the directory exists, it is added to `sys.path` prior to the system site-packages directory.  For example, with a Debian Linux installation:

```
$ python2.7 -c 'import site; print(site.USER_SITE)'
/home/nad/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
$ ls -l /home/nad/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
ls: cannot access /home/nad/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages: No such file or directory
$ python2.7 -c 'import sys; print(sys.path)'
['', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7']
# user site-packages dir doesn't exist so it's not in sys.path
$ mkdir -p ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
$ python2.7 -c 'import sys; print(sys.path)'
['', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/home/nad/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7']
# now user site-packages dir exists so it is in sys.path and before /usr/lib ones
```

Comment: But how do I ensure that this will override the same older global package already on the system?

Comment: If you read the link given by @Ned, then it will use `userbase` to install that module so it will not override the system default module. When you import any module then it will check in `userbase`'s lib's `python` directory and then it will check for the system `python` directory.

Comment: Either method uses Python's search order, available in the `sys` module as `sys.path`, to ensure the user directory is searched first.

Comment: See updated answer for an example of `sys.path` search order.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that elements further down in sys.path had precedence over the ones above.  This turns out not to be the case.  That aside, I decided to use virtualenv as you suggested as it seems to be the cleanest way to get easy_install and pip working without any modifications.